# Hibernate Many-to-Many self join duplicate entries

Tags: hibernate

I try do save a graph to database.
It consists a simple class with "tag" attribute.
This class may have parents and children.

After save the root class, all graph is saved too, but when a node have two parents, these two parents are duplicated in database.

Here is the mapped node class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="acttest")
public class ActivityTest {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_activity")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idActivity;


    @Column(name="tag")
    private String tag;


    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,  fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinTable(name="dependencies",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_master")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_slave")})
    private Set<ActivityTest> nextActivities = new HashSet<ActivityTest>();


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="nextActivities",  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ActivityTest> previousActivities = new HashSet<ActivityTest>();

    (getters and setters)
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session s;
        ActivityList al = new ActivityList();

        al.addRoot("A");
        al.addNextActivity("A", "A1");
        al.addNextActivity("A", "A2");
        al.addNextActivity("A", "A3");

        al.addNextActivity("A1", "B");
        al.addNextActivity("A1", "BA12");

        al.addNextActivity("A2", "BA12");

        al.addNextActivity("B", "B1");
        al.addNextActivity("B", "B2");

        al.addNextActivity("B2", "B2.2");


        s = ConnFactory.getSession();
        s.beginTransaction();

        s.save( al.getRoot() );

        s.getTransaction().commit();
        s.close();
}
```

Here is the wrapper list:

```
public class ActivityList {
    private List<ActivityTest> activities;
    private ActivityTest root = null;

    public void addRoot( String tag ) {
        if ( root == null ) {
            ActivityTest activity = new ActivityTest( tag );
            activities.add(activity);
            root = activity;
        }
    }

    public ActivityList() {
        activities = new ArrayList<ActivityTest>();
    }

    public void addNextActivity( String master, String next ) {
        ActivityTest newAct = new ActivityTest( next );
        activities.add(newAct);
        for ( ActivityTest act : activities  ) {
            if ( act.getTag().equalsIgnoreCase( master )  ) {
                act.getNextActivities().add( newAct );
            }
        }
    }

    public ActivityTest getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public List<ActivityTest> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

    public void setActivities( List<ActivityTest> activities ) {
        root = null;
        this.activities = activities;
        for ( ActivityTest act : activities  ) {
            if ( act.getPreviousActivities().size() == 0 ) {
                root = act;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The graph I design to test:

[image]

The graph table:

[image]

And the dependency table:

[image]

Note the duplicity of "BA12" node: onde for "A1" child and other for "A2" child.

How can I make one instance of "BA12" node?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all!

Solved by changing the wrapper class:

Added a private method do search for already created object:

```
private ActivityTest getActivity( String tag ) {
    for ( ActivityTest act : activities  ) {
        if ( act.getTag().equalsIgnoreCase( tag )  ) {
            return act;
        }
    }
    return new ActivityTest(tag);
}
```

and changed the addNextActivity to:

```
public void addNextActivity( String master, String next ) {
    ActivityTest newAct = getActivity( next );
    activities.add(newAct);

    for ( ActivityTest act : activities  ) {
        if ( act.getTag().equalsIgnoreCase( master )  ) {
            act.getNextActivities().add( newAct );
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry again. My mistake.